# Javascript failing to validate form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having trouble pinpointing why my javascript code is failing to validate the form on the bottom. Any help is appreciated. I'm new and learning when in comes to javascript.

Here's the javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validate(){

//Initialize array
var field = new Array;

var field = [document.getElementById('first_name'),document.getElementById('last_name'),document.getElementById('address'),document.getElementById('eadress'),document.getElementById('city'),document.getElementById('state'),document.getElementById('telephone'),document.getElementById('comments')];

//Error tracker
var error = 0;

//Validation Loop
for (i=0;i<field.length;i++)
{
    if (field[i].value == "")
    {
        error++;
    }
}

//If no errors are present, submit
if (error == 0)
{
document.contact-form.submit();
}

//Else, display alert
else {
    alert("One or more fields are empty.");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the form:

```
<div id="registration">
        <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" id="contact-form">

        <h2>Contact Us
        </h2>

        <div>
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="required"  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" class="required" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <input id="address" name="address" type="text" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input id="city" name="city" type="text"  />
        </div>

        <div >
            <label for="state">State:</label>
            <input id="state" name="state" type="text"  />
        </div>

        <div >
            <label for="zip">Zip:</label>
            <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text"  />
        </div>

        <div>

            <label for="eaddress">Email address:</label>
            <input id="eaddress" name="eaddress" type="text" class="required"/>


        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
            <input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text"  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Comments:</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="4" name="comments" id="comments"  ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label></label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  I'm guessing that the DOM isn't loaded yet.

Comment: I'm just trying to test it in browser, no DOM. How would I go about referencing/adding DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected your code. it seems that in the array you are asking for eadress and the field is eaddress with 2 d's

Answer (score 0):

In the script, you misspelt eaddress as eadress :)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled one of the fields ids in your array definition document.getElementById('eadress') is eaddress in HTML id attribute